# OpenFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled doesn't work under Vista or 7?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-vista, openfiledialog

If I specify OpenFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true, my program still shows the old XP-style dialog. Any idea why this would happen? This is after I enable theming in Main()

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Primary());
}
```

and this is my dialog code:

```
private void OpenProgramFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog programFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    programFileDialog.Filter = "Program files (*.exe;*.lnk)|*.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    programFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
    programFileDialog.Title = "Select program file";
    programFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true;
    programFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;

    DialogResult fileResult = programFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (fileResult != DialogResult.OK)
        return false;

    programFileDialog.Dispose();
}
```

So why would AutoUpgradeEnabled not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid setting `programFileDialog.ShowHelp=true`.  The `ShowHelp` property is not compatible with the Vista/7 file dialog UI.  The open file dialog will still show a question-mark help icon.

Comment: Ah, this is what it was! This was set because ShowHelp=false made my app freeze, and at the time, I didn't specify [STAThread] for "thread-safe". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Windows Vista or Windows 7 style dialogs you should use the Microsoft Windows API Code Pack: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack. This includes all the Windows 7 Style dialogs.

Comment: While that's true, a service pack to the .NET Framework ensured that you got the new all-singing, all-dancing version of the Common File Dialog unless you deliberately set some options that made it look like you wanted old school. I'm a big Code Pack advocate but only if you need it.