# Closing a OpenFileDialog causes application to hang for 3-4 seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, openfiledialog, mahapps.metro

In my `WPF` application which uses the `Caliburn.Micro` and `MahApps.Metro` frameworks, i open instances of `OpenFileDialog` from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. After opening and closing this dialog, the rest of my application hangs for approximately 3 to 4 seconds. This is also true when using the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.

I've done some research myself and come up with a handful of posts complaining of the same issue, and the solutions they found was two fold:

1. Quick fix: set the `ShowHelp` property to `true`
2. Proper fix: Ensure it's running in `Single Threaded Apartment` mode.

The `ShowHelp` fix works for me by using a non-vista style dialog, but from an `UX` perspective on Windows Vista and newer, it doesn't look right. The other thing for me then would be to ensure it's in `STA` mode.

`WPF` uses `STA` by default, but I tried writing my own main method and explicitly stating `[STA]` but had no luck. I added the below snippet to my code, but the output is `State: STA`, indicating there should be no issue.

```
Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState());
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
```

I've also tried launching the `OpenFileDialog` on a new `STA` thread, and while it launches and doesn't hang my application, it also isn't modal anymore. I've also tried joining the new thread, but it still hangs after closing.

#### Question

Is there a known, underlying issue with `OpenFileDialog`and if so, are there alternate ways of launching the FileDialogs that may avoid this hanging?

Sources for the `ShowHelp` and `STA` comments:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941240/openfiledialog-autoupgradeenabled-doesnt-work-under-vista-or-7#comment3001225_2941499)
- [blog](http://wishmesh.com/2011/06/call-to-openfiledialog-or-savefiledialog-hangs-or-freezes/)

Comment: OpenFileDialog injects a very large amount of code into a process.  Shell extensions, programmers tend to have a lot of them installed.  Not always of the best quality.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to narrow down to the troublemaker, ask questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: OpenFileDialog is a Winforms class. The 'correct' way to have such a functionality is to implement some kind of IOpenFileDialogService, MVVM style.

Comment: You could try to use the Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315188/open-file-dialog-and-select-a-file-using-wpf-controls-and-c-sharp

Comment: I've also tried the `Win32` namespace, and it's the same issue